# OpenStack Error(Neutron network service)

Tags: python, openstack, centos7, openstack-neutron

## My Enviroment

- CentOS7
- OpenStack(Liberty)

## Problem

neutron port-show net-ID

Unable to find port with name 'net-ID'

How do I fix this problem?? Please help

---

### /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini

```
[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = public:ens6f0
[vxlan]
enable_vxlan = False
[agent]
prevent_arp_spoofing = True
[securitygroup]
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
enable_security_group = True
```

---

### /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini

```
[ml2]
type_drivers = flat,vlan
tenant_network_types =
mechanism_drivers = linuxbridge
extension_drivers = port_security
[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = public
[ml2_type_vlan]
[ml2_type_gre]
[ml2_type_vxlan]
[ml2_type_geneve]
[securitygroup]
enable_ipset = True
```

Comment: Show us some logs of the linuxvridge-agent, ml2. All of the logs are inside this directories in case of Ubuntu: /vat/logs/

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command to get the net-ids.

> neutron port-list

After getting the net-ids of different network devices(router, DHCP etc..), execute the following command with it.

> neutron port-show "net-id you got from previous command"